# How can I protect my domain names without exposing too much personal information?

Tags: privacy, dns-domain

I guess more specifically I want to know how to ensure I retain ownership by having sufficient contact information in the Administrative, Technical and Billing contact fields, but without exposing too much personal information.

I was thinking about using a P.O. Box instead of my address. Are there any downsides to that?

Or does this contact information have little to do with stopping social-engineering type attacks where someone might try and steal ownership of my domain names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many domain name services offer private registration. This means that they act as a go between for any information forwarded to the domain and yourself, protecting your privacy.

I.e. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domains_by_Proxy

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This option seems to place a lot of trust in the service provider. I think the best option for me might still be the P.O Box. At least then all someone will have is my name, phone number, and P.O.Box, and not my physical address.

Comment: Going from name+phone number to address doesn't sound like a big step to me.

Comment: If you have a common enough name, it may work to provide first initial, last name, PO Box (different town than your residence), an email address you use for nothing else, and an alternate phone number (consider a Google Voice or similar account that you use for nothing else). If you have an uncommon name, you may want to find a trusted nominee who is willing to have their info in the registration. But Private Registration is a viable and widely accepted option.

Comment: Also, make sure you have your domain registrations Locked with your registrar. This will prevent domain registration transfers without access to your current registrar account.

Answer (score 0):

You can opt for private registration offered by domain registrars, where your personal information will be guarded.
When you go for private registration, your details will be guarded by Domains By Proxy where you get two unique and powerful layers of security.

To make sure how your information is displayed after private registration, you should use any of the freely available domain lookup services to check your domain name and see how your Administrative, Technical and Billing information's are displayed.